# A way to find the kernel with the help of matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

---

Let $\mathcal{S}=\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}: A^T=A\}$ the vector space of the real symmetric $2\times2$-matrix and $$\mathcal{B_1}=\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}，
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}，\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\}$$
$$\mathcal{B_2}=\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}，
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}，\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\} $$ are the basis of $V$. Let then $f\in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$ with $$f(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix},\quad f(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix},\quad f(\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

1. Find the matrix representation of $[f]_{\mathcal{B_1},\mathcal{B_2}}$
2. Find the Kernel(f)
3. Calculate the dimension of image(f)

---

The first question is simple and is $[f]_{\mathcal{B_1},\mathcal{B_2}}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 &2\\ 0 & 0 &0\\1 &-1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

Is there a way to find the kernel of a linear map $f\in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$ with the help of two basis $B_1,B_2$ and the matrix representation $[f]_{B_1,B_2}$? I tried this way that $f=\Phi_{B_2}^{-1}[f]_{B_1,B_2}\Phi_{B_1}$, where $\Phi$ is the coordinate linear map. But what is the inverse of $\Phi$?

If the second question is solved then the third is also simple which is $\dim(\mathbb{R}^{2,2})-\dim(\ker(f))=4-\dim(\ker(f))$

Could you please give some advices? Thank you!

Comment: Your answer to the third is incorrect. In fact, we have
$$
\dim(\operatorname{im}(f))) = \dim(S) - \dim \ker f = \color{red}3 - \dim \ker f
.$$

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the kernel (AKA nullspace) of a matrix? There is a common approach that uses row-reduction.

Comment: the nullspace of the matrix representation $[f]_{B_1,B_2}$ is also the nullspace of f, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no: the nullspace of $[f]_{\mathcal{B_1,B_2}}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, but the kernel of $f$ is a subspace of $S$.